# C++ accessing container class method

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ inheritance and I'm trying to access a container class method.

I've got an **Environment** class that has a public method called **drawText()**.

The **Environment** class has a Robot class **robot** inside it:

```
robot = new Robot;
```

How can I call **drawText()** from inside the **Robot** class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're using `new` casually in C++, it's probably wrong. C++ isn't the same as Java.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Should I go with Robot robot; then?

Comment: Yes, that's the best way

Comment: There's no defined way for an object to know about what contains it. If you need it, the Robot object will have to do something like receive a pointer or reference to the containing class.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question and I'm sorry I close-voted :(

Comment: When you are a beginner, you should put a bit more code and try to explain it to help us get your question better and avoid flags and delete requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in Robot.h Enviroment reference

```
//robot.h    
namespace envrNamespace    
{    
   class Environment;
};

namespace rbtNamespace
{
class Robot
{
    Environment* _parent;
    void setParent(Environment* _env) {_parent = _env;};
    Environment* getParent() {return _parent;};
    //...
}    
};

//Environment.cpp
Robot* robot = new Robot();
robot->setParent(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
class Environment {
public:
  Environment() { }
  ~Environment() { }

  setRobot(Robot* robot) {
    robot_ = robot;
  }
  drawTest() { }

private:
  Robot* robot_;
};

class Robot {
public:
  Robot(Environment* env) {
    env_ = env;
  }

  void foo() {
    env_.drawTest();
  }

private:
  Environment* env_;
};
```